# Star Wars Ship - Which LEGO Set Is This?

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

I received a large assortment of free *LEGO* from a family member, and can't seem to locate which ship this may be.

I'm thinking it's part of the *Clone Wars*. Anyone recognize it?

[image]

Comment: Welcome Derek.  You seem to have left out the image you reference.  Would you please edit your question to include the image?  It will be much easier to recognize with that.

Comment: Where's the fun in that??? Had an issue with shrinkage...pic now loaded

Answer (score 7):

Its at least two sets. [image]
[image]

Set #7674 "*[V-19 Torrent](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7674-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)*".
and...
Set #8087 "*[TIE Defender](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8087-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)*".

**Extra Credit:**

Upper left hand corner.
[image]

Set #6747 "*[Race Rider](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=81733#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)*".

Comment: Well done Rin. My apologies if my earlier downvote on another question caused negative emotions .. A downvote does not mean your contribution is not appreciated, it just means that the answer doesn’t suit the question. All water under the bridge of course since you deleted the question. Hope we’re good though...

Comment: Wow!!!! This helps tremendously Rin. No wonder I couldn't find any images that fit what pieces we had. Looking forward to digging through the pile to put the Tie Defender together.  Unbelievable job catching the Race Rider too just by noticing the tire????